# Customize SSRS Report Viewer to display report description before execution (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2012

How can I customize SSRS Report Viewer to display report description ("description" attribute of rdl) before execution (Sharepoint 2013 integration mode).

Comment: where and when exactly do you need? in edit mode or running mode?

Comment: Runnung. Befre I select parameters and execute the report.